# Uncaught type error (loading jQuery scripts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, typeerror

Good day! I use jQuery Tablesorter for pagination. I get this error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function viewTags:24
    (anonymous function) viewTags:24
    fire jquery-1.10.2.js:3048
    self.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:3160
    jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.10.2.js:433
    completed
```

in the browser's console. The problem is highly because of the loading of scripts. This is the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>   

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Please help me figure this out. Thank you very much!

Comment: please try removing your 5th column in dynamic table and try both in thead and tbody

Comment: Thanks @KarthickKumarGanesh I removed the fifth column in both thead and tbody but the problem persists.

Comment: can you please make fiddle with your genereted table output

Comment: Here the table paginates http://jsfiddle.net/XZP6R/5/ and this is what I'm supposed to do. Thanks.

Comment: its working fine in fiddle

Comment: Yes and the problem may be in the arrangement (i really don't know) of the load of scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Update to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>   

<script>
   jQuery(function($) {
      var availableTags = @Html(Json.toJson(tagNames).toString); 
      $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
      });

      $("table").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra'] }) 
                .tablesorterPager({
                          container: $("#pager"),
                          size:5
      }); 
   }); 
</script>
```

---

You don't need to have two jQuery's `doc ready` block, one is enough to put those functions in it. Also you have to do a stack order of your script this way.
If still issue is there then try to inspect in network tab of inspector (*chrome*) to see if some library is not getting loaded properly.

Comment: Thanks I copied your answer but the error is still there and won't paginate

Comment: checkout the network tab if any library is not loaded properly.

Comment: No load error. Just the uncaught type exception. Thanks.

Comment: `jQuery(function($) {` try changing this line. may be something `$` is not that what you think there.

Comment: Thanks but I copy-pasted your edit, it says `ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined `

Comment: Thanks @Jai I included jQuery Migrate Plugin. That removed the `msie` error but the `uncaught type error` is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include jQuery once. Currently you've loaded it twice, so you can remove:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

After that, you need to include `tablesorter` plugin after core jQuery file since your `jquery.tablesorter.js` require `jQuery` to work:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you remove the first jQuery file like I've suggested in my answer? Remember to follow the script's order like above.

Comment: Yes thanks I copy-pasted that and now I have two lines of css and 4 lines of js. But the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

please review this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>



 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTable").tablesorter({
            widthFixed : true,
            widgets : ['zebra'],
            headers : {
                0 : {
                    sorter : false
                },
                1 : {
                    sorter : false
                },
                2 : {
                    sorter : false
                },
                3 : {
                    sorter : false
                },
                4 : {
                    sorter : false
                }
            }
        }).tablesorterPager({
            container : $("#pager"),
            size : 5
        });
    });
```

please use only this code, remove all other things and try

Comment: Thank you but there's still this uncaught type error in the tablesorter line.

Comment: Still does not, unfortunately. The problem most probably is the script loading. Thanks

Comment: please give  your whole page output ?

Comment: The output and the code is almost like this http://jsfiddle.net/XZP6R/9/ so it's really confusing why it won't work on mine.

Comment: please check my code above ,please remove all other scripts and just try above with your  table and see what you get